Configuring Facets in GeoNetwork 4.4.4
I am currently trying to configure the home page facets and search facets in my GeoNetwork 4.4.4 application, but I've encountered some challenges.
Issues Encountered:
Missing config-summary.xml:
According to the documentation, I should be able to configure facets in the config-summary.xml file. However, I cannot find this file in the expected location (WEB-INF/config).
Editing CatController.js:
I attempted to modify CatController.js located in src/main/webapp/geonetwork/catalog/js, but my changes don't seem to take effect. I'm not sure if I'm missing a step or if there's a caching issue.
User Interface:
The user interface doesn't seem to provide options to configure these facets directly.

I'm trying to do the same in 4.2.9. I can't see config-summary.xml either, I'm guessing you need to create it. I did find this: https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/3.12.x/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config-summary.xml
The documentation says "All facet configurations are stored in the user interface configuration". Although I can't cant that to work either.

This works in 4.2.9, so it might work for you.
In the User interface console in the admin console:

Click the "Choose an option to customize" drop-down.
Select "Search application / Facets configuration"
Scroll down to Facets configuration and you will see the text box now populated with the config.

